# PigLatin mismatched input ';' expecting LEFT_PAREN (IBM BIGINSIGHTS)

Tags: apache-pig, biginsights

Sorry for a naive question. I am a newbie. I have a Pig script and getting below error:

```
ERROR [main]      org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt     - ERROR 1200: <file xxx.script, line 2, column 20>  mismatched input ';' expecting LEFT_PAREN
```

This is how my scipt looks like:

```
a = load 'xxx.csv' using PigStorage(',') as (person:chararray,store:chararray,spent:float);
b = group a by store;
dump b;
```

Here's the stacktrace:

```
ERROR 1200: <file xxx.script, line 2, column 20>  mismatched input ';' expecting LEFT_PAREN

org.apache.pig.impl.logicalLayer.FrontendException: ERROR 1000: Error during parsing. <file xxx.script, line 2, column 20>  mismatched input ';' expecting LEFT_PAREN
at org.apache.pig.PigServer$Graph.parseQuery(PigServer.java:1689)
at org.apache.pig.PigServer$Graph.access$000(PigServer.java:1409)
at org.apache.pig.PigServer.parseAndBuild(PigServer.java:342)
at org.apache.pig.PigServer.executeBatch(PigServer.java:367)
at org.apache.pig.PigServer.executeBatch(PigServer.java:353)
at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.executeBatch(GruntParser.java:140)
at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.processDump(GruntParser.java:769)
at org.apache.pig.tools.pigscript.parser.PigScriptParser.parse(PigScriptParser.java:372)
at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:198)
at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:173)
at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt.exec(Grunt.java:84)
at org.apache.pig.Main.run(Main.java:607)
at org.apache.pig.Main.main(Main.java:156)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:94)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:619)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:212)
Caused by: Failed to parse: <file /home/biadmin/xxx.script, line 2, column 20>  mismatched input ';' expecting LEFT_PAREN
at org.apache.pig.parser.QueryParserDriver.parse(QueryParserDriver.java:241)
at org.apache.pig.parser.QueryParserDriver.parse(QueryParserDriver.java:179)
at org.apache.pig.PigServer$Graph.parseQuery(PigServer.java:1676)
... 17 more
```

Comment: However, if i use:    b = group a by $1;              then it works fine

Comment: I don't see any issue with the pig script. Can you add the content of input csv here ? Are the values separated by comma ? Does any of the field value have single quote (') as value ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply  @Murali Rao but it gives me the same error. Surprisingly group a by $1 works flawlessly. Yes it is comma separated. No fields have a single quote

Comment: @Hadoop Learner The  Variable name that you use  for $1 is store, but unfortunately store  is a KeyWord in Pig.. So Please use a different variable name for $1. Then it will work

Comment: Thank you so much @Surender Raja. It worked by renaming store to deptStore. I was doing it with $1 but name reference definitely help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed by @Surender Raja, store is a keyword and after changing it to deptStore, I could reference it with the name rather than $1